# How to create sprite animation from particles animation by means of tweens?

Tags: javascript, animation, phaser-framework

Here is such a code snippet:

```js
var game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.CANVAS, 'phaser-example', { preload: preload, create: create });

var emitter;

function preload() {
    game.load.image('wasp', 'assets/glass.png');
    game.load.image('glass', 'assets/glass.png');
    game.load.image('water', 'assets/blue-raster-floor.png');

}

function create() {

    game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);

    game.add.tileSprite(0, 344, 800, 256, 'water');

    emitter = game.add.emitter(game.world.centerX, 200);

    emitter.makeParticles('glass');

    emitter.setXSpeed(-200, 200);
    emitter.setYSpeed(-150, -250);

    emitter.bringToTop = true;
    emitter.setAlpha(0.1, 1, 500);
    emitter.setScale(-2, 2, 1, 1, 3000, Phaser.Easing.Sinusoidal.InOut, true);
    emitter.gravity = 300;


    emitter.start(false, 5000, 700, 50);

    game.time.events.add(3000, destroyEmitter, this);
}

function tweens(cash) {
    var bugs;
    var index = 0;
    var data;
    var pos = [];
    var tween;

    var tweenData = { x: 0, y: 0 };

    tween = game.make.tween(tweenData).to( { x: 100, y: 400 }, 2000, "Sine.easeInOut");

    tween.yoyo(true);

    data = tween.generateData(60);

    bugs = game.add.group();
    pos.push(new Phaser.Point(32, 0));
    pos.push(new Phaser.Point(300, 100));
    pos.push(new Phaser.Point(600, 70));

    bugs.create(pos[0].x, pos[0].y, 'wasp');
    bugs.create(pos[1].x, pos[1].y, 'wasp');
    bugs.create(pos[2].x, pos[2].y, 'wasp');

    tween.onUpdateCallback(function () {
        bugs.getAt(0).x = pos[0].x + data[index].x;
        bugs.getAt(0).y = pos[0].y + data[index].y;
        bugs.getAt(1).x = pos[1].x + (data[index].x / 2);
        bugs.getAt(1).y = pos[1].y + data[index].y;

        //  Inverse one of the values
        bugs.getAt(2).x = pos[2].x - data[index].x;
        bugs.getAt(2).y = pos[2].y + data[index].y;

        index++;

        if (index === data.length)
        {
            index = 0;
        }
    });

    tween.start();
}

function destroyEmitter() {
    console.log(emitter);
    emitter.destroy();
    tweens();
}
```

As you can see, I have made the *particle-animation*. Such steps need to be taken:

1. *Particle-animation* should be cached in the form of a set of shots (textures)
2. *Particle-animation* should be deleted. I have already done it (by means of ‘*destroy*‘)
3. Instead of the particle animation *sprite animation* should be realized by means of the function tweens using received textures 
   and passing these textures as the argument of the function tweens
   Any refractoring is welcome.

Comment: Have you tried doing it yourself before asking?

Comment: No, sorry,  I can't deal with it just right now (I have no possibility), but I really need solution.

Comment: This site is here to help you, not do the job for you. Maybe somebody else knows how to do and will help you...

Comment: I'm sorry if i offensed some users, policy this web-site or rules. This is my first question. It's not a job, really.

Comment: I've updated question and code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Phaser, the emitter particles are of the relatively simple `DisplayObject` class which do not support animations like the `Phaser.Sprite` does. Btw I don't know if using tweens is the best way to animate particles, because I suspect it will be heavy on CPU usage, using Sprite animations on the other hand is a bit more "light weight".

But either way, you could create a custom particle class which contains the code for your particle animation (using tweens, animations, timers, whatever) and then set that custom class as the `emitter.particleClass`, see a code example in link below:

http://codetuto.com/2016/02/phaser-animated-particles/